# Dynamically calculate column values based on Date

Tags: date, excel-formula, dax

I need( Is it possible?) for Values in a column to calculate themselves based on Date from a Sales_Fact table;

for example, in 2015 there were  new motorcycle models sold that had various model years( 1998,2015,2016 etc..)

I am trying to create new calculated column that would read as :

If the Model Year is within 2 years of current Year, return  [market name], otherwise return " Misc model"

```
[Relevant Models]= if(Model year = YEAR(Sales_Fact[Date]),[Market name],"MiscModel"))
```

or
 I tried Sum of relevant models:

```
Sum Current Models YTD:=CALCULATE([Sum of Units],Prod_DIM[Model year]=Year(Sales_Fact[Date]))
```

It needs to be dynamic because it is based upon the  year chosen from the Sales_Fact table.

Misc Models need to be included in the YTD total but not in the List of Models sold  for the year in question.

See link below with the table on the right as desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so clear what you are trying to do but for

```
[Relevant Models]= if(Model year = YEAR(Sales_Fact[Date]),[Market name],"MiscModel"))
```

you can use this formula in excel:

```
=IF(YEAR(NOW())-2<=A1,B1,"MiscModel")
```

where: A1 is placed models year, B1 is placed market mane and C1 is placed the formula

Comment: The Year(Now()) portion wold have to be Dynamic and  use the date field from a DATE_DIM table, therefore altering the values in the Column [relevant Models] and flagging them if they are relevant or not.     For example the year 2012 would have different relevant models than 2000 etc.. Could a logic function be used to created dynamic values?

Comment: You always can change Year(Now()) whit specified cell.